# C# equivalent of Java's Generic Method that extends Comparable

Tags: c#, generics, comparable

I want to convert the following class from java to C#:

```
public class Generics {

    public static <T extends Comparable <T>> T findMax(T a, T b) {
        int n = a.compareTo(b);
        if (n < 0) {
            return b;
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: So where's your C# code and what problems are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: I'm new with generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [generic constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class Generics {
    public static T FindMax<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        int n = a.CompareTo(b);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            return b;
        }
        else
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```